# Strategies for search across disparate data sources

Tags: search, enterprise

I am building a tool that searches people based on a number of attributes.  The values for these attributes are scattered across several systems.

As an example, dateOfBirth is stored in a SQL Server database as part of system ABC.  That person's sales region assignment is stored in some horrible legacy database.  Other attributes are stored in a system only accessible over an XML web service.

To make matters worse, the the legacy database and the web service can be really slow.

What strategies and tips should I consider for implementing a search across all these systems?

Note:  Although I posted an answer, I'm not confident its a great answer.  I don't intend to accept my own answer unless no one else gives better insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider using an indexing mechanism to retrieve and locally index the data across all the systems, and then perform your searches against the index. Searches would be an awful lot faster and more reliable.

Of course, this just shifts the problem from one part of your system to another - now your indexing mechanism has to handle failures and heterogeneous systems, but that may be an easier problem to solve.

Another factor is how often the data changes. If you have to query data in real-time that goes stale very quickly, then indexing may not be practical.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get away with a restrictive search, start by returning a list based on the search criteria corresponding to the fastest data source.  Then join up those records with the other systems and remove records which don't match the search criteria.

If you have to implement OR logic, this approach is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

While not an actual answer, this might at least get you partway to a workable solution.  We had a similar situation at a previous employer - lots of data sources, different ways of accessing those data sources, different access permissions, military/government/civilian sources, etc.  We used [Mule](http://www.mulesource.org/display/MULE/Home), which is built around the Enterprise Service Bus concept, to connect these data sources to our application.  My details are a bit sketchy, as I wasn't the actual implementor, just an integrator, but what we did was define a channel in Mule.  Then you write a simple integration piece to go between the channel and the data source, and the application and the channel.  The integration piece does the work of making the actual query, and formatting the results, so we had a generic SQL integration piece for accessing a database, and for things like web services, we had some base classes that implemented common functionality, so the actual customization of the integration piecess was a lot less work than it sounds like.  The application could then query the channel, which would handle accessing the various data sources, transforming them into a normalized bit of XML, and return the results to the application.

This had a lot of advantages for our situation.  We could include new data sources for existing queries by simply connecting them to the channel - the application didn't have to know or care what data sources where there, as it only looked at the data from the channel.  Since data can be pushed or pulled from the channel, we could have a data source update the application when, for example, it was updated.

It took a while to get it configured and working, but once we got it going, we were pretty successful with it.  In our demo setup, we ended up with 4 or 5 applications acting as both producers and consumers of data, and connecting to maybe 10 data sources.

Comment: i like this idea the best although there might be a much easier one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of moving the data into a separate structure?

For example, Lucene stores data to be searched in a schema-less inverted indexed.  You could have a separate program that retrieves data from all your different sources and puts them in a Lucene index.  Your search could work against this index and the search results could contain a unique identifier and the system it came from.

http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/
(There are implementations in other languages as well)

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)? It may not be the perfect solution but I might give you starting point to work from.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters I'd parallelize the queries to the different systems.  That way we can minimize the query time.

You might also want to think about caching and aggregating the search attributes for subsequent queries in order to speed things up.

You have the option of creating an aggregation service or middleware that aggregates all the different systems so that you can provide a single interface for querying.  If you do that, this is where I'd do the previously mentioned cache and parallize optimizations.

However, with all of that it you will need weighing up the development time/deployment time /long term benefits of the effort against migrating the old legacy database to a faster more modern one.  You haven't said how tied into other systems those databases are so it may not be a very viable option in the short term.

EDIT: in response to data going out of date.  You can consider caching if your data if you don't need the data to always match the database in real time.  Also, if some data doesn't change very often (e.g. dates of birth) then you should cache them.  If you employ caching then you could make your system configurable as to what tables/columns to include or exclude from the cache and you could give each table/column a personalizable cache timeout with an overall default.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pentaho/Kettle to copy all of the data fields that you can search on and display into a local MySQL database
http://www.pentaho.com/products/data_integration/

Create a batch script to run nightly and update your local copy. Maybe even every hour. Then, write your query against your local MySQL database and display the results.